# What are evaluation metrics for regression-type neural net?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, neural-networks, error-function, mean-square-error

When neural networks are used to solve classification tasks, different evaluation metrics can be used such as Precision, Recall, classification error and F1-score, which are calculated based on counting correctly/incorrectly predicted labels.

What would be similar evaluation metrics other than cost-function itself in cases of regression problems, where a function is predicted?